# Android : How to store address into native Contact app from our app

Tags: android, contactscontract

In android native contact app, some mobiles have single address field called `Address`. some mobiles have multiple fields like `street, city, state, country, zip code`. 
just I want to know how can I store address into the native app from our app. And also how to retrieve the `address` from the native app.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. After a long time i got one solution  ,so you can use this below code :

```
public boolean addContact() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (haveContactPermission()) {
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, TextViewUserFullName.getText()) // Name of the person
                    .build());


            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, homephone) // Number of the person
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME).build()); // Type of mobile number

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, mobilephone) // Number of the person
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build()); // Type of mobile number

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, getBitmapFromURL(image))
                    .build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());


            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS, TextViewWifeName.getText()).build());

            try {
                ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                return true;
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ContactInfoZone.this, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // error
                return false;
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ContactInfoZone.this, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // error
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},
                    PERMISSION_CONTACT_NUMBER);
            return false;
        }

    } else {


        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, TextViewUserFullName.getText()) // Name of the person
                .build());



        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, homephone) // Number of the person
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME).build()); // Type of mobile number

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, mobilephone) // Number of the person
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build()); // Type of mobile number

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, getBitmapFromURL(image))
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
                .build());


        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS, TextViewWifeName.getText()).build());

        try {
            ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            return true;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactInfoZone.this, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // error
            return false;
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactInfoZone.this, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // error
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that will help you.

Comment: ok thks....can you give me some tips about fast reading contact....reading 400 contacts its taking 2 minutes ....please tell me any fast way to query contacts with all data.

Comment: There are two number of-if conditions.
 First one for version is above 23 or not ?
If the version is below 23 then not any issue we can directly add contact.
else if condition is above 23 then (second if condition is here) we want to ask for contact permission is given or not , if yes then we can add contact ,if no then create request Permissions .

Comment: please give me your java code for query. then i can try for you.

Comment: pls tell u r mail id

Answer (score 0):

its copy past maybe it will help you

```
     String DisplayName = "XYZ";
     String MobileNumber = "123456";
     String HomeNumber = "1111";
         String WorkNumber = "2222";
      String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
     String company = "bad";
   String jobTitle = "abcd";


ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList <     

ContentProviderOperation > ();

  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
  ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
 .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
 .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
 .build());

 //------------------------------------------------------ Names
  if (DisplayName != null) {
  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
  ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
 DisplayName).build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number                     
 if (MobileNumber != null) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
 newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
     .build());
 }

//------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
if (HomeNumber != null) {    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
     .build());
}
 //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
 if (WorkNumber != null) {     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
     .build());
  }

//------------------------------------------------------ Email
  if (emailID != null) {ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,   
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
     .build());
}//------------------------------------------------------ Organization
 if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) { ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,    
 company) .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,   
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE,     
 jobTitle)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,  
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
     .build());
 }

// Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                 
  try {
 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
  } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(myContext, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(),    
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I asked for address field here address only not there @ shivpal jodha